# jQuery load multiple array not work

Tags: jquery

I have this code for post multiple array using jQuery `load` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#results").load("http://localhost/cms/controller/pagination.php");  
  $(".pagination").bootpag({
    total: 10, // total number of pages
    page: 1, //initial page
    maxVisible: 5 //maximum visible links   
  }).on("page", function(e, num){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');
    $("#results").load("http://localhost/cms/controller/pagination.php",{'page':num,'order':test});  //initial page number to load
  });
});
```

But in action `{'page':num,'order':test}` not work for me.

How do fix this problem?

Comment: `load()` is async, not sure what you are trying to do here. And passing data object to `load()` method makes it POST request, maybe that's your issue

Comment: From where is this 'num' in   'function(e, num)' coming from?

Comment: @A.Wolff: i need to change my method to `.ajax() post` ?

Comment: @NewCod3r I don't know this plugin `bootpag` and not sure how you are handling it server side in `pagination.php`. Is this server side script expecting GET or POST request?

Comment: @A.Wolff: http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#example-pro . Work With POST/GET

Comment: I was asking regarding `pagination.php`. Is it expecting GET or POST request (or both)?

Comment: @A.Wolff I think Both

Comment: @NewCod3r You think??? Check it instead

Comment: @A.Wolff: http://jsfiddle.net/628zL/3/

Comment: @NewCod3r I don't understand the purpose of your jsFiddle regarding my question. That's said, to send a GET request, try: `$("#results").load("http://localhost/cms/controller/pagination.php?num=" + num);`??? Just be aware, i still don't understand all the purpose of your posted code because you didn't explain what you are expecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97767/discussion-between-newcod3r-and-a-wolff).

Comment: `$("#results").load("http://localhost/cms/controller/pagination.php?num=" + num);` not work and i can see any action